# Android repo tool: is there any way to apply a patch command during the repo sync operation

Tags: android, patch, repo

First of all I would like to describe an environment
that is related to my question (as simple as it could be).

1. Android repo tool should be used to deal with 2 repositories
2. git repository A contains a simple txt file, file.txt
3. git repository B contains a patch for the file.txt from the A repository

I did a short research (xml schema of the repo manifest)
**edit**: *dead link should be:* https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md

according to this document repo can:

- copy file (Element copyfile)
- create a symbolic link (Element linkfile)
- there are also remove project and include elements

Is there any way to:

- set a decency between the 2 repositories above
- apply a patch from the repository B to the text.txt file from
  repository A with the
  repo / repo sync
  command?

Maybe this requires some additional tools
or adjustments that somehow skipped away from my attention.

Thank you for your help.